# Which data type to use while creating table when column is a mix of whole numbers as well as decimals?

Tags: database-design, amazon-redshift, sqldatatypes

I am **creating a table in Redshift** (based on PostgreSQL), a few columns of that table's source data are a **mix of whole numbers as well as decimals**.

If I set decimal(5,5) it throws error for integers, if I set integer it throws error for decimals, which type fits both?

Comment: number(5,5)....

Comment: What do you think the second number (the *scale*) in `decimal` means? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Scale is the number of decimal digits in the fractional part of the value, to the right of the decimal point.. I don't think you got my question. I want a type to handle both integer and decimal type for the same column.

Comment: Right, so you need something that can store digits both *before* and *after* a decimal point. So setting the scale equal to the precision doesn't let you do that because it's saying that all of the digits have to come after the decimal point.

Comment: Got you, buddy! I was missing out the very basic point decimal(i+d,d), and mistakingly doing decimal(d,d). Thanks!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, number(n,s) doesn't work in Redshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many digits of your integers do you need to reasonably be able to store? Call that number `i`.

How many digits after the decimal do you need for your decimals? Call that number `d`.

You now know that you want a `decimal(i+d,d)`. But you need to check whether such a combination is valid in the documentation. If it is, great. If not, you need to trade off some digits to arrive at something acceptable.